# Can python support a huge amount of requests on Socket?

Tags: python, multithreading

I found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/114642/) and used it to build a TCP proxy from my `game clients` to my `game servers`.

I have around 1000 clients all online simultaneously.
I noticed that the script is giving error `Can't start a new thread`.

My question is how to get around this?
Or should I consider just using C instead?

Correct me if I'm wrong. I guess there is too many clients, the multithreading of python can't cope.

Answer (score 2):

If you want such a large amount of connections you should be using events instead of multithreading. Multithreading is much slower and uses much more resources in cases like these.

Take a look at the following libraries:

- http://eventlet.net/
- http://www.gevent.org/
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html